# My cardview is overlapping all layouts (cards)

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I am trying to make a cardview showing different options for a menu, but the cards are just overlapping each other, i have followed multiple tutorials and repeat things exactly as shown but the cardview isnt working properly, how do i fix it or make it work properly? am i doing something wrong?
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainMenu">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:background="@drawable/userpanel">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3 " >

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/cardcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/cardcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xplpA.png)

idk why is it showing like that, i did this before but got the project deleted because my pc died and worked perfectly, and now it isnt